# Fetch all rows for a foreign key if even one row matches condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `profile` and `props`.

`profile.ID` is a foreign key in `props` with other columns.

I need to query the table `props` with a condition, but return all the rows that have the same foreign keys as those of the rows that have satisfied the condition.

Example:

```
+---------------------+
|ID  |  name  | value |
+---------------------+
|1   |  eng   | 60    |
|1   |  mat   | 70    |
|1   |  sci   | 80    |
|2   |  eng   | 90    |
|2   |  mat   | 40    |
|2   |  sci   | 50    |
|3   |  eng   | 70    |
|3   |  mat   | 40    |
|3   |  sci   | 50    |
+---------------------+
```

For table above, if I query `name = 'mat' AND value < 50`, I get

```
+---------------------+
|ID  |  name  | value |
+---------------------+
|2   |  mat   | 40    |
|3   |  mat   | 40    |
+---------------------+
```

Instead I need

```
+---------------------+
|ID  |  name  | value |
+---------------------+
|2   |  eng   | 90    |
|2   |  mat   | 40    |
|2   |  sci   | 50    |
|3   |  eng   | 70    |
|3   |  mat   | 40    |
|3   |  sci   | 50    |
+---------------------+
```

For those who question the purpose, I am trying to implement dynamic attributes for the profile; and a need the complete list of attributed to further filter those with any other conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use an `INNER JOIN` to accomplish this instead of a `WHERE id IN...` statement:

```
SELECT  A.ID,
        A.Name,
        A.Value
  FROM  props A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  ID
                  FROM  props
                  WHERE (Name = 'mat' AND value < 50)) B ON B.ID = A.ID
```

So in `B` get all the `ID`s that match the criteria then simply join them to the `props` table (alias `A`).

Comment: I also thought about this solution but it needs subquery too and a simple subquery is propably easier to understand.

Comment: this is faster than in

Comment: It depends on db engine. Oracle 11 query optimizer (and maybe 10 too, I don't know) converts itself these cases to JOINs AFAIK. I've read that most query optimizers do that nowadays.

Comment: And it's still a subquery that references the same table. JOINS are faster if they're implemented instead of subqueries. Here the cost of subquery is in both cases the main cost for DB engine.

Comment: The inner join has a significant performance improvement. I am using mysql though, and it seems the InnoDB engine does not convert the INs to JOINs.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
  FROM props
  WHERE id IN
  (
     SELECT id
       FROM props
       WHERE name = 'mat' AND value < 50
  )
```

Comment: just tried it and came back to see this answers. Works like a charm. Can add as answer in 8 minutes

Comment: sub-query that references the same table in MySQL is really not good practice